# Access content on a server through http?

Tags: http

I have some folders and files that I need to copy to a remote server so it can be accessible through http, like: `http://myhost/data`

One approach is to put it in the tomcat/webapps folder but then it will disappear when I reinstall/update tomcat. Is there an alternative location for my files on the server that will still be available through http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using an apache2 web server with a virtual host does the trick

Answer (score 0):

you can keep your file in your home directory and create a soft link for them in the webapps